How to use different connection strings and code depending on development or production branch in .NET framework?
The projects in question are built with .NET framework and use TFVC for version control.
I have two branches for each project, production and development. Every time something like an entity model or a web service is added, the app.config or web.config file changes.
My current approach is to manually edit the .config file in the production branch after merging. Is there a more automated approach?
I also have code that needs to change based on the database. For example, code containing role IDs. I currently manually edit the code file after merging. Can this be automated?
